How can I parse a string into html elements based on a regex match?
I am using discord's api to read in messages send to the a server, and their messages embed an emoji id that calls their cdn.
For example, "This is a string with some emojis <:PepeHey:584511188944027705> and heres a second emoji <:PepeHey:584511188944027705>".
I have the regex statement to extract the ID, but I need to essentially break down my input string into:
<p>This is a string</p> <img src={discord.com/id}/> <p>and heres a second emoji </p> <img src={discord.com/id2}>.
To clarify, my problem isnt writing the regex statement to get the IDs, its just breaking down my message into multiple html elements based on where those regex matches occur.
I tried to just replace the id occurences with , but it read in those as plain text so my string would just contain .

Please include the attempts in which you tried to solve your question.

I think that’s the one https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace
